# Load support data set from NetCDF file (Tropomi Sentinel 5P) with GDAL.NET

Tags: gdal, c#, netcdf, gdal.net

Been trying to load two data sets from a Tropomi NetCDF file (N2O measurements). I can manage to load some data sets, which are right under `PRODUCT`, but not others which are under `PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/`.

I've been trying to load them the same way as I do the other datasets.

```
using (Dataset ds = Gdal.Open(filePath, Access.GA_ReadOnly))
{
  list = ds.GetMetadata("SUBDATASETS").Cast<string>().ToList();
}
```

The first thing that draws attention is that the `PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/latitude_bounds` and `PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/longitude bounds` do not appear in the `SUBDATASETS`.

If I try to address it manually, I do get a dataset back, but it's invalid as any subsequent read from it fails:

So, this fails:

```
var latBounds = Gdal.Open("HDF5:D:\\Downloads\\tropomi_no2_20181227\\S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20181227T114003_20181227T132133_06244_01_010202_20190102T140322.nc://PRODUCT/SUPPORT_DATA/GEOLOCATIONS/latitude_bounds", Access.GA_ReadOnly);
float[] latBoundsBuffer = new float[latBounds.RasterXSize * 1];
var latBoundsRaster = latBounds.GetRasterBand(1);
var scanline = latBoundsRaster.ReadRaster(0, 0, latBounds.RasterXSize, 1, latBoundsBuffer, latBounds.RasterXSize, 1, 0, 0);
```

Any idea how these auxiliary datasets can be loaded? If useful, the product data sets are [described here](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/2474726/Sentinel-5P-Level-2-Product-User-Manual-Nitrogen-Dioxide).

Also, Panoply shows and load the datasets just fine:

[image]